# Does the definition of $\exp$ as the solution to $y'=y, y(0)=1$ allow us to actually calculate its value at a given point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Let $\exp:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ denote the solution of the ODE

$$
y'=y, \quad y(0)=1.
$$

Say I want to calculate $\exp(x_0)$ for some given $x_0$, is there any way to do this without using the other definitions?

Comment: Yes. You can create the Taylor Series of $e^x$ using this differential equation.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to derive a "new" equivalent definition of $e^x$ from the given ODE definition and then to use this "new" definition to approximate $e^{x_0}$? Or are you trying to avoid this method?

Comment: @JonWarneke No, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things, you could get an approximate numerical value by solving the differential equation numerically.

EDIT: Methods you can use by hand or with a small amount of programming include the [Euler](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/euler/euler.html), 
[Improved Euler](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/impeuler/impeuler.html)
and [Fourth-Order Runge-Kutta](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/runge/runge.html) methods.  Most mathematical software systems (e.g. Maple, Mathematica, Matlab etc) include more powerful methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate on some basic method to do that?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD "Numerical methods for ordinary differential equations" will return an astonishing amount of information in a google search.

Comment: Probably the best known numerical method is Euler's method. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Example; this does the exact calculation you want with $x_0 = 4$.

Comment: Hahaha, Euler's method.  And then *improved* Euler's method.  :D